# How to use conditions with multiple subnets?

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml, zabbix

I am trying to write a playbook that will install zabbix agent.
This line in the code "line: Server" line needs to change to one of the proxy servers depending on the host IP space.

Lets say If one of the hosts in the inventory is in 10.20.3.0/32 space then i want this "line: Server=" block to use a different proxy than if the host is on 10.10.3.0/32 IP space.

I feel like I can use 'when' condition to differentiate between both but how would I tell the playbook to check for the IP on the host and depending on that IP space use one of the values.

Thanks in advance.

```
 name: Modifying zabbix-agent.conf file for Server(proxy)
        lineinfile:
          dest: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
          regexp: ^Server=.*
          insertafter: ^# Server=
          line: Server=10.10.3.7
```

Answer (score 1):

> If one of the hosts in the inventory is in 10.20.3.0/32 space then i want this "line: Server=" block to use a different proxy than if the host is on 10.10.3.0/32 IP space

If the gathered fact `ansible_default_ipv4.network` doesn't automatically do what you want, then the [`ipaddr` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#ip-address-filters) will go a long way toward helping you, when combined with a `dict` that maps between the machine's subnet and its assigned proxy IP:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    # or you can of course use "group_vars/all/all.yaml" or your favorite mechanism
    # this just makes the answer easier to digest
    subnet_to_proxy:
      '10.20.3.0': '10.20.3.1:3128'  # or whatever
      '10.10.3.0': '10.10.3.1:8080'
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: I will use {{ subnet_to_proxy[ansible_default_ipv4.network] }} for {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
```